# Sporadically not receiving texts sent to me from iMessage users-- how do you deal?

Tags: sms, mms, ios, samsung-messages

As most here are probably aware, there are issues communicating between iMessage and Android MMS/SMS apps. For me, I will send a message to an iMessage user and they may or may not receive it with no error message. Sometimes it's the other way around. I have tried to [deregister my number from iMessage](https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage/) (my number is not registered with them apparently) and I've made sure I have sufficient data and/or wifi and watched it happen (or not happen) in real time. I've heard of [AirMessage](https://airmessage.org/) but chances of someone with an Android phone having a spare Apple pc to leave powered on all day seems quite slim. To this day I can't get my American peers to install WhatsApp without major pushback. As someone who does not participate in major social media platforms (for my mental health), this has resulted in many missed opportunities time and time again.

So I have a 2 part question:

1. What exactly is the technical explanation for this phenomenon?
2. In late 2023, what is the state of the art "solution" for this ongoing frustrating problem? Has anyone out there "fixed" inter-platform messaging for themselves?

Comment: As Apple refuses to implement RCS and iMessage is proprietary and iOS only the only way to receive messages from iMessage is via SMS and may be MMS. For SMS I don't see any point where you could do something that has an effect on the reception of messages. For MMS make sure your phone is correctly configured.

Comment: In my opinion the reason for this problem is that users are too lazy and only follow the most simplest way. For Apple this is iMessage and for Android WhatsApp. Both messengers are IMHO bad for multiple reasons like privacy. Secure alternatives like Signal exist....